# Why does piping commands into telnet result in intermittent connection failures?

Tags: bash, email, smtp, telnet, netcat

As a cheap hack workaround on a number of servers that don't have the `mail` command, a script was written that echoes SMTP commands into a telnet session. The relevant part of the script looks like

```
telnet mailserver 25 << EOF
EHLO $HOST
MAIL FROM: root@$HOST
(and so on)
EOF
```

This intermittently fails, with a "connection closed by remote host". A `tcpdump` of a failing session confirms that the Postfix mail server is closing the connection *immediately* after sending the `220` welcome message. That is, none of the input redirection has made it over the wire.

So far, I haven't been able to pin down the conditions of the failure, but I can confirm that using `nc` (netcat) works flawlessly, every time.

A number of questions on this site and Stack Overflow are adamant that `nc` is the right tool for this job. I am interested in **why** this is the case.

- Why is the failure intermittent?
- Why does the mail server hang up before a single line of input from the redirected is sent over the wire?
- Why does `telnet` break but `netcat` not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely happening because of delays from the mail host being ignored.  Sending an email has a requirement of a connection, then a response.  If the MAIL FROM is issued before the server has responded the sending will fail.  Indeed some servers rely on slightly delaying this HELO response specifically to stop this pump and close connection behaviour as it is often done by spammers.

There are ways to handle this (not using Telnet being the best one), but otherwise using some kind of chat script.    If that is not available to you, manually adding delays will not fix the problem, but it can substantially limit the issue.

As you appear to be using some kind of Linux environment, using nc (netcat) over Telnet is considered best practice. The last part of [this](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_email_using_netcat.html) link shows how to use netcat and "expect" to better send an email and correctly handle timings.

Comment: Netcat is a replacement for telnet, not something to be used over telnet.  If the lack of delay was the problem, netcat would suffer the same fate.

Comment: In this part of the world "over" in this context "over" implies "in preference to".  Using nc to talk on top of telnet is non-nonsensical in this context.

Comment: I see, but still why would nc vs telnet make any difference at all?  They both connect to the remote host and send what you give them.

Comment: Precisely the question being asked here...

Comment: @MikeyT.K. Telnet is considered to be an interactive tool while netcat is focussed on scripting. The issue is not telnet but netcat as much as adding time for appropriate responses from the mail server.